# What happens when already destroyed activity by OS is revoked by user from recent apps?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, android-recents

As far as I know, an app that is already destroyed by Android System resides in recent apps. For example, I launched my app and navigated through several activities. Then quit, and opened several other apps and not launched my app again for several hours. My last opened activity will stay in the recent apps even though it has been destroyed by the system. My question is what life-cycle methods will be run when I touch my app from the recent apps list and in which order?  Also what will happen to my data in the activity that is still shown on the recent apps? Does it get created from the start? Do I still have an activity stack? and will my base application class be re-created also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to LifeCycle of an activity, after your app will be killed by the android OS (to get memory for more prioritized apps), your activity will start from onCreate() method, and go through the cycle, as usual) What about your data:

1. values in views (like EditText) will be restored if your view have ids.
2. your variable values I suggest you to save and restore with onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState().

Comment: ok, I edited my question. Do I get data from onRestoreInstanceState from a destroyed activity? Will my base application class will be re-created from the start. What happened to its variables, are they already destroyed?

Comment: Do I get data from onRestoreInstanceState from a destroyed activity? - yes! 
Will my base application class will be re-created from the start? - yes! 
What happened to its variables, are they already destroyed? - they will be destroyed after your app process will be killed, because while links to your variables values exists, they consume system memory, that's why they will be killed )

Comment: But this should mean that data i save on saveİnstanceState stays forever even though the application is destroyed. It is a bit weird to me.

Comment: It is not documented how Android treats the Bundle data... It's everything I can help )))

Comment: Thank you alexander, it seems onSaveInstance saves data to disk, so my data is not stored in memory forever, rather it stays in a disk cache, that makes sense then.
I just put a Log command on my onCreate function of Application class, but it doesnt get triggered when my process is killed after hours and my app is started through recent apps. Only thing I wonder now is how my application class behaves. I would be pleased if you could update it in your answer

Comment: So. according to the android life cycle scheme, your process was not killed, if you have no logs from the onCreate() method. It looks like your app just restoring from the back stack. I suggest you to put logs into onRestart() method and have a look. If you will get logs hence your app just restoring. Sorry, but there is no way, to catch if your app process was killed...

Answer (score 0):

There is two scenario here:-

- If your app still in recent apps much time and other apps need memory your app will be killed by Android OS, and if you open it again it will start from splash-screen.
- If your app stayed short time in recent-apps without need for memory the last activity you used will be opened, starting it's lifecycle from `onStart()`.

Once you press home button It will call `onStop` without destroying it unless OS or user do.

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim, what happens is that last opened activity is opened again. I dont have a splash-screen. I have a flow of tasks that starts from my launcher activity. But when the app is destroyed by OS and later some further acitivity of my app is called through recent apps, since my launch activity is not called , my tasks wont start.

Comment: I probably have to consider the scenario that my app wont always start from my launch activity.

Comment: @MehmetKatircioglu Well, I didn't understand you as well, but I think you have a problem with your app architect/logic.

Comment: @MehmetKatircioglu If your app need to start from launcher-activity you can clear the stack one the `onStop` called, but that's not user friendly if he reopen your app and start from begin,

Comment: As long as my base application lives I dont need such kind of behaviour, because the variables I obtained from tasks is stored in the objects that is referenced in application class. When user destroys the app on his will, and starts the app again, my sequence of flow will work again. The calling of some intermediate activity from recent apps is the only condition that I'm facing problem.